# Using MYSQL optimise table with innodb_optimize_fulltext_only and innodb_ft_num_word_optimize options, how do I know when it's finished?

Tags: mysql, database, indexing, full-text-search

The MySQL documentation says:

To avoid lengthy rebuild times for full-text indexes on large tables, you can use the innodb_ft_num_word_optimize option to perform the optimization in stages. The innodb_ft_num_word_optimize option defines the number of words that are optimized each time OPTIMIZE TABLE is run. The default setting is 2000, which means that 2000 words are optimized each time OPTIMIZE TABLE is run. Subsequent OPTIMIZE TABLE operations continue from where the preceding OPTIMIZE TABLE operation ended.

What I can't find however, is any way to determine that I have invoked the optimize function enough times.  The output from each invocation is identical

Comment: Have you experimented any?